# Arch Linux Systemd wont detect hibernate events

Tags: systemd, services

I currently have a system service setup to lock my laptop every time it hibernates, in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` is have

`HandleLidSwitch=hibernate`

but for some reason my service is never run

also here is my service

```
[Unit]
Description=Lock X session using i3lock
Before=hibernate.target

[Service]
User=user
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/home/user/scripts/locksleep.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=hibernate.target
```

the service never gets called in the system logs either

Answer (score 0):

I believe your unit needs to declare it needs to run before `systemd-hibernate.service`, which is the service that actually puts the system in hibernate state.

(I'm thinking if your unit is running in parallel with `systemd-hibernate.service`, then it's quite possible the system goes into hibernate before your script gets to run.)

So, replace `Before=hibernate.target` (which you don't need) with `Before=systemd-hibernate.service`. Additionally, you need to tell systemd to wait until the script execution is completed, so you need to add `Type=oneshot` to the `[Service]` section.

I'm assuming your unit is enabled too, since that's necessary for hibernate.target to pull it... Without enabling it, nothing would trigger it.

So I'm guessing this will be enough to address the issue with your unit not running properly before hibernate...

But note there are more appropriate ways to accomplish what you want to do, which is lock the screen before hibernate.

The correct way to do it is by using the [inhibitor interface](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/inhibit/). The page that describes this mechanism lists locking the screen as one of the uses for this interface:

> A screen lock tool wants to bring up the screen lock right before suspend, and delay the suspend until that's complete.

In short, you register a D-Bus client and tell systemd you want notifications when hibernate is about to happen, then watch for a `PrepareForSleep()` signal from D-Bus, at which point you can lock the screen.

Ideally, this should be done by the screen saver itself, so adding support there would be ideal.

If using the inhibitor interface is not an option, then a simpler way to execute a script before suspending is to drop a script under `/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` and then checking the passed arguments to see if it's being called before hibernate. This should achieve the same effect as you're trying to get from the service unit, but probably a lot simpler to set up.

See the [man page for systemd-hibernate.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-suspend.service.html) for more details on how scripts under `system-sleep/` work.

Comment: I made the modifications you suggested but that did not fix it, and also it is enabled

Comment: I really suggest you try the alternatives, such as the script under `system-sleep/`, see the man page for the calling conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I realized my laptop was failing to hibernate because I did not have a swap partition